# The general principle of smart contracts for bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-pools, smartcontracts

As far as I know, there is the possibility of realizing smart contracts using the Bitcoin blockchain. Explain how a smart contract works on the Bitcoin blockchain. I am interested in the general architecture: in what language is the contract written, what is and where is the machine that processes it, etc.
This is the most general question in order to understand and clarify the mechanism, for better immersion in development.точнения механизма, для лучшего погружения в разработку.

Comment: Bitcoin doesn't have native smart contracts. Ethereum is famous for smart contracts. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/ can answer in that case.

Comment: @MCCCS that isn’t really true, Eth just has more expressive smart contract capabilities than BTC.

Comment: @chytrik This is what I had in mind. What does more expressive smart contract capabilities mean? Can you tell me where to dig?

Comment: @Gybernaty the Bitcoin scripting language is designed to be verifiable, secure, dependable. It is slightly limited in some functions because of this. On the other hand, Eth's smart contracting language is designed to be easy-to-use, more full featured, ~Turing complete, etc. But the trade-off is verifiability and security, which are in fact **very** important considerations (see: eth DAO hack, eth multi-sig bugs, etc). The question I linked above does a better job explaining this